# Best way to save configuration data in database AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

I have some configuration data i want to read from the spring boot application. The configuration can get bigger and bigger, therefore i dont want to create yaml file in the project. I was thinking about what would be the cheapest way to save this data in AWS. Like DynamoDB? or do you have maybe better and cheaper ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB would be a good solution, it will allow you to quickly retrieve and edit the config set. DynamoDB also has a [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/?did=ft_card&trk=ft_card) of 25RCU/WCU and 25GB storage per month, which I assume you will fall into that category making it a free option.

The only limitation with DynamoDB is that 400KB is the maximum item size, however, you can split your item up into an "item-collection" where all of the items share the same partition key and the sort key identifies the sub components.

[AWS App Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/what-is-appconfig.html) is the correct service to use for application configuration setup but it is not cheaper than using DynamoDB for free, so your trade off is down to what you need from your configuration data.

Answer (score -2):

Ignoring the `cheaper` part of the question, the AWS AppConfig is the right tool for storing configuration, as it comes with many useful features out of the box (like gradual deployment, rollbacks, validation, etc). You can find pricing information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/pricing/). Note that the total price will also depend on how often you refresh configuration (i.e. your cache invalidation time). Other tools, like S3, might be cheaper, but are not as well suited for configuration use case.

Answer (score -4):

> what would be the cheapest way to save this data in AWS

The cheapest way to save data in AWS is to use S3 Intelligent Deep Archive or S3 Glacier Deep Archive for $0.00099 per GB.

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: `S3 Glacier Deep Archive` is an archive storage service. Recover object takes 3-4 hours. Depending context but probably not the right way to save a configuration file. However, you are right, this is cheap storage.

Comment: The question was "what is the cheapest way to save data in AWS" and S3 Glacier is the cheapest way. Recovery was not mentioned in the question.